# Tooltip with Cytoscape JS and Angular8

Tags: javascript, tooltip, cytoscape.js

I am looking for an example of showing Tooltips when hovering over nodes in Cytoscape graph.
I have seen several examples with popperjs and with qtip , non of them was working (for me at least)

cytoscape-qtip seems to be deprecated

example here (Tippy.js)

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper

seems not to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code from [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper/blob/master/demo-tippy.html) just fine, I made some adjustments myself, so that the tooltips appear on hover:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));

  function makePopper(ele) {
    let ref = ele.popperRef(); // used only for positioning

    ele.tippy = tippy(ref, {
      // tippy options:
      content: () => {
        let content = document.createElement("div");

        content.innerHTML = ele.id();

        return content;
      },
      trigger: "manual" // probably want manual mode
    });
  }

  cy.ready(function() {
    cy.elements().forEach(function(ele) {
      makePopper(ele);
    });
  });

  cy.elements().unbind("mouseover");
  cy.elements().bind("mouseover", event => event.target.tippy.show());

  cy.elements().unbind("mouseout");
  cy.elements().bind("mouseout", event => event.target.tippy.hide());
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: when using let ref = ele.popperRef(); i get "ele.popperRef is not a function" , probably related to the fact that i user Angular8

Comment: Well you still have to import the extensions to angular8 yourself (not that familiar with that myself), have you done that?